# Updating a "complex" Entity in JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

```
entity = MainDao.findByUUID(getEntityManager(), dto.getUuid());

            
Adress i = new AdressDao().findById(dto.getIdAdress());
i.setPhone(dto.getPhone());
entity.setAdress(i);
return MainDao.update(getEntityManager(), entity);
```

I have a main Entity in which there is a @ManytoOne relationship to Adress. I want to update the field "phone" inside adress, how do I do it? My code fails to do so.

Hope you can help me out, it seems there is no "patch" method inside JPA. I would love to know the best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `@ManyToOne` doesn't `cascade` the changes (as it refers to a parent which may be have other child associations).

You can do either of below,

1. save the changes of Address entity via your `AddressDao` like `addressDao.save(addressEntity)`
2. use `@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`.

1st options is preferable.

Read about `CascadeType` to utilize wisefully.